# Netcdf4: save changes on editing

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf4

I have a problem with a netcdf file including data of mean sea level pressure. I need to do an EOF analysis on that data, so I need to weight data with the square root of the cosine of latitude. I open the dataset, extract variables, and multiply them with the weight.

I checked the calculation printing the MSLP values for a fixed time series and longitude before and after the weighting. The second print is correct and is exactly what I want, but the data seems not to be saved. In fact, when (after closing the dataset) I reopened it and I reprint the data, they are the original ones and they are not changed.

Python:

```py
dset = Dataset(newpath,'r+')
lat=dset.variables['lat'][:]
msl=dset.variables['msl'][:]

j=0 #lat counter
print(msl[0,:,0])   #first print check (fixed times series and longitude)
while j<160:
    msl[:,j,:]=msl[:,j,:]*math.sqrt(math.fabs(math.cos(lat[j]*0.015708))
   j=j+1
print(msl[0,:,0])   #second print check (correct weight in output)
dset.close()

print ('____________________________________________________')

dset = Dataset(newpath)
lat=dset.variables['lat'][:]
msl=dset.variables['msl'][:]
print(msl[0,:,0])    #third print check (original data)
dset.close()
```

Output:

```
[101021.06 100858.19 100738.31 100654.19 100615.19 100593.69 100562.56
100511.81 100424.94 100336.31 100258.81 100210.44 100158.69 100104.44
100056.94 100008.06  99980.31  99977.81  99994.44 100021.31 100072.69
100129.69 100195.56 100277.31 100384.06 100517.81 100673.69 100818.69
100937.81 101032.44 101123.56 101225.31 101333.56 101422.81 101508.94
101596.69 101717.69 101827.06 101929.19 102002.31 102085.81 102153.69
102106.94 101980.81 101912.19 101924.94 101964.31 102036.94 102144.56
102230.81 102190.31 102142.06 102129.06 102114.19 102074.81 102042.19
102006.56 101979.81 101939.44 101901.81 101856.69 101799.69 101737.31
101677.81 101612.69 101551.06 101489.06 101424.19 101343.06 101250.44
101160.81 101095.19 101048.06 101033.31 101053.56 101084.81 101087.44
101099.44 101110.44 101126.56 101138.06 101147.31 101155.94 101171.19
101184.44 101209.94 101230.31 101256.69 101282.19 101309.06 101336.06
101372.81 101408.69 101452.81 101490.69 101540.81 101587.69 101642.81
101695.19 101751.56 101803.31 101860.44 101909.06 101956.31 101996.06
102028.94 102050.44 102060.56 102055.81 102040.56 102016.69 101979.31
101924.06 101845.06 101743.94 101633.31 101505.81 101370.44 101216.69
101061.56 100902.94 100739.06 100571.44 100416.94 100282.56 100150.94
100012.94  99876.06  99737.19  99624.56  99533.69  99483.81  99457.81
 99473.81  99510.69  99571.06  99627.94  99690.19  99731.69  99777.81
 99788.44  99837.69  99868.44  99936.81  99964.44 100129.44 100214.56
100257.94 100333.81 100380.06 100444.94 100485.81 100578.06 100684.31
100783.81 100866.69 100939.44 100999.81 101061.06 101111.31]
   [ 41619.645  43605.746  45517.273  47355.477  49134.914  50851.395
 52497.957  54074.137  55574.52   57021.02   58424.58   59799.477
 61129.76   62418.176  63672.594  64889.86   66086.44   67267.34
 68430.6    69571.84   70702.53   71810.86   72900.21   73976.79
 75048.58   76118.43   77183.93   78220.58   79216.72   80173.18
 81106.555  82028.58   82936.46   83809.59   84661.07   85495.07
 86338.734  87154.586  87946.35   88695.16   89435.1    90143.61
 90732.586  91231.664  91762.88   92349.1    92941.94   93548.02
 94169.59   94755.02   95205.89   95631.93   96073.62   96496.445
 96879.016  97250.93   97603.02   97946.78   98260.68   98560.51
 98836.43   99084.21   99310.16   99522.38   99712.65   99889.96
100050.59  100192.15  100301.43  100383.13  100451.66  100527.97
100606.76  100701.945 100816.305 100925.96  100991.34  101050.41
101092.79  101124.6   101136.1   101129.66  101106.88  101075.016
101025.43  100972.31  100898.305 100814.47  100713.92  100598.87
100468.02  100330.875 100176.836 100014.86   99830.57   99642.12
 99434.164  99217.91   98982.5    98734.42   98465.234  98184.53
 97878.83   97554.945  97206.97   96835.48   96436.2    96009.18
 95551.17   95066.375  94556.56   94017.25   93444.54   92833.24
 92185.11   91511.78   90806.73   90078.13   89316.77   88537.77
 87739.2    86919.49   86079.88   85234.65   84389.22   83528.47
 82644.56   81743.57   80822.664  79904.28   78983.86   78075.61
 77164.734  76264.016  75355.77   74440.77   73497.734  72532.51
 71525.42   70494.195  69409.86   68323.33   67193.75   66057.68
 64861.55   63718.73   62486.844  61190.336  59873.098  58495.234
 57082.75   55608.207  54109.78   52561.516  50947.504  49257.734
 47489.68   45635.43   43693.46   41656.83 ]
____________________________________________________

[101021.06 100858.19 100738.31 100654.19 100615.19 100593.69 100562.56
100511.81 100424.94 100336.31 100258.81 100210.44 100158.69 100104.44
100056.94 100008.06  99980.31  99977.81  99994.44 100021.31 100072.69
100129.69 100195.56 100277.31 100384.06 100517.81 100673.69 100818.69
100937.81 101032.44 101123.56 101225.31 101333.56 101422.81 101508.94
101596.69 101717.69 101827.06 101929.19 102002.31 102085.81 102153.69
102106.94 101980.81 101912.19 101924.94 101964.31 102036.94 102144.56
102230.81 102190.31 102142.06 102129.06 102114.19 102074.81 102042.19
102006.56 101979.81 101939.44 101901.81 101856.69 101799.69 101737.31
101677.81 101612.69 101551.06 101489.06 101424.19 101343.06 101250.44
101160.81 101095.19 101048.06 101033.31 101053.56 101084.81 101087.44
101099.44 101110.44 101126.56 101138.06 101147.31 101155.94 101171.19
101184.44 101209.94 101230.31 101256.69 101282.19 101309.06 101336.06
101372.81 101408.69 101452.81 101490.69 101540.81 101587.69 101642.81
101695.19 101751.56 101803.31 101860.44 101909.06 101956.31 101996.06
102028.94 102050.44 102060.56 102055.81 102040.56 102016.69 101979.31
101924.06 101845.06 101743.94 101633.31 101505.81 101370.44 101216.69
101061.56 100902.94 100739.06 100571.44 100416.94 100282.56 100150.94
100012.94  99876.06  99737.19  99624.56  99533.69  99483.81  99457.81
 99473.81  99510.69  99571.06  99627.94  99690.19  99731.69  99777.81
 99788.44  99837.69  99868.44  99936.81  99964.44 100129.44 100214.56
100257.94 100333.81 100380.06 100444.94 100485.81 100578.06 100684.31
100783.81 100866.69 100939.44 100999.81 101061.06 101111.31]
```

Comment: Can you refine your question to highlight the difference between the current behavior and what you expect?

Comment: The correct behavior is that of the second print, the second block of information [...] in output before the straight line. I would expect the print when I reopen the dataset (after the straight line) to be identical to the second but it is the same of the first print (the original data not weighted).

Answer (score 2):

At this point at the beginning of your script:

```
msl=dset.variables['msl'][:]
```

`msl` is just a Numpy array and no longer related to your NetCDF file, so you need to write the array back to the NetCDF file:

```
dset.variables['msl'][:] = msl
```

just before you close the NetCDF file the first time.